# Why do i need the reference of the controller in the view, in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, controllers

I have the following:
**CustomersController.js**

```
(function(){

//dejo afuera el controller en sí.
var CustomersController = function($scope){
            $scope.sortBy = 'name';
            $scope.reverse = false;

            $scope.customers = [{joined:'1990-12-12',name:'Gabriel',city:'Arg',orderTotal:'989.4267'},{joined:'1979-04-08',name:'Pablo',city:'Chile',orderTotal:'123.4'},{joined:'1980-12-12',name:'Martin',city:'Peru',orderTotal:'25'}]; 
            $scope.doSort = function (propName){
                $scope.sortBy=propName;
                $scope.reverse=!$scope.reverse
            };
        };

        CustomersController.$inject = ['$scope'];

        angular.module('customersApp').controller('CustomersController', CustomersController)


}());
```

**APP.JS**

```
(function(){var app = angular.module('customersApp',['ngRoute']);}());
```

And finally **Index.html**

```
<html ng-app="customersApp">
<body> 
  <div ng-view></div> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="Controllers/customersController.js"></script>

  </body>   
 </html>
```

---

If you are linking the controller to the module and the module to the Index.html, why I still need this

```
"script src="Controllers/customersController.js"
```

in the index.html?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Angular 'modules' are logical modules. They don't provide a transport, the framework leaves that to you. If you don't physically load the script where the controller is defined, it won't be loaded.

Comment: You are using AngularJS, not Angular. Please update the tag and question so that others can appropriately help you.